# Combinatorics question: teams vs missions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, problem-solving

I know it's a combinatorics question, I'm just not sure how to approach it.

Let's say we have $7$ types of agents: $A,B,C,D,E,F,G$. Agents work in teams of $4$. We send teams on missions, with each mission requiring three different types of agents. For example, $\{ A,B,C \}$. So, the team of $ \{ A,B,C,D \}$ can do four types of missions: $\{ A,B,C\}$, $\{ A,B,D \}$, $\{ A,C,D \}$ and $\{ B,C,D \}$.

**The question is:** how many teams of $4$ do I need to cover all possible missions? And what are these teams?

**My progress so far:** I know the upper bound is 35 (just create a team for every mission as "mission requirements + any other member"), and the lower bound is 35 \ 4 ~= 9 (each team covering almost exactly 4 different missions, and I have an intuition it's impossible to construct). As a programmer, my first way of approaching this would be "just simulate every combination of teams", and I might do just that if other approaches fail. I'm interested in how to do it mathematically. My combinatorics classes were a long time ago.

Comment: Have you made an attempt at approaching the question?

Comment: ABCD can do 4 types of missions, but not *simultaneously*  If this is treated as acceptable, then ABCDEFG can cover all types of missions of 3 . Pl clarify what is the intent of the question.

Comment: In our optimal case, each mission is covered by the last number of teams possible (preferably only 1). Since each team covers 4 missions, the number of teams required is less than or equal to $\lfloor\frac{210-1}{4}\rfloor+1$. I will try to find time to write a rigorous proof.

Comment: @IraeVid I know that the best case would be 210/4, but I'm not sure we can construct teams like these. Won't they overlap significantly?

Comment: @MariuszPopieluch I know the upper bound is 210 (just create a team for every mission as "mission requirements + any other member"), and the lower bound is 210/4 (each team covering exactly 4 different missions, and I have an intuition it's impossible to construct). As a programmer, my first intuition is "just simulate every combination of teams", and I might do just that if other approaches fail. I'm interested in how to do it mathematically. My combinatorics classes were a long time ago.

Comment: @trueblueanil this is a team of size 7. In my question max size of the team is 4.

Comment: Actually, there are only $35$ combinations using $3$ of $7$ agents. (The number $210$ would mean that the order of agents is important, which seems unlikely in this context.)

Comment: Guys, please upvote the question, so it's not negative. I edited it so it is better expressed. It is an interesting question. Not deep, but interesting. We've had much more basic ones than that one here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I have pasted one of your comments into the question itself. MSE requires askers to add context into their questions (such as showing your own work on the question, explaining where the question arose from, or detailing your level of knowledge). Hopefully my edit helps prevent this question from being closed. If you disagree with any of my changes, you can always undo them by rolling back my edit, or making a new edit.

Comment: @paw88789 you're correct, it's combinations, not permutations (my english / statistics knowledge failed me here). But this makes the problem even tighter. 35 / 4 is 9 (rounded up to nearest whole) and I doubt these 9 teams can be constructed.

Comment: Funny thing, the number of possible 4-teams is equal to the number of possible 3-teams — there's 1 to 1 relation between them. Each 3-team corresponds to the 4 types of agents not present in it.

Comment: I'm trying to construct these sets by hand and while the first 4 teams easily cover 4 distinct missions each (16 in total), it gets more difficult to find a team that doesn't overlap with any of the previously chosen, so the lower bound is definitely higher than 9.

Comment: There's another approach I can take: listing out all 35 possible teams and remove those whose missions are completely covered by another teams. Haven't tried that approach though.

Comment: @SergeShirokov This problem is really fun and I've been thinking about it for a while. I'm just working on the details of an answer. Did you realise that if you have a collection S of the 4-sets such that each X and Y in S differ by at least two elements, that set will cover |S|*4 unique 3-sets? This is a crucial, if not obvious observation, and it's probably best to start with that. S need not be unique (I have no proof for this, but it seems easy to show), and it seems that S can't be larger than 5 elements (I have no proof for that either, but there should be an elegant argument for this).

Comment: @SergeShirokov "so the lower bound is definitely higher than 9" -- ah you got it! That's good. You can increase this set to 5 elements though :) There will be a pair that only shares 1 element, and all other pairs will differ by exactly 5 elements.

Comment: @SergeShirokov It can be done with 15 teams, it seems. Whether it can be done with less is a tricky question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a somewhat intuitive 12-team solution:

- ABC with each of E, F, G
- EFG with each of A, B, C
- D with each of ABE, BCF, CAG
- D with each of AEF, BFG, CGE.

A computer search reveals that there's no 11-team solution, so this is optimal.